# Cannot find Postgres header while working with Wt c++

Tags: c++, postgresql, wt, ubuntu-20.04

I'm currently working on `Ubuntu 20.04` and I am building a web application with [WebToolkit](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). I want to use a Postgresql database to store my data. I built `Wt` from source, following [these steps](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/InstallationUnix.html).

Unfortunately, when I include the header file `Wt/Dbo/backend/Postgres.h` in my code, I get the following error

`cannot open source file Wt/Dbo/backend/Postgres.h`

Indeed, the directory `Wt/Dbo/backend` includes only `Sqlite3.h` and `WDboSqlite3DllDefs.h`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is that non-existing header file supposed to contain, and which software should provide it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't build the `Postres` backend while building `Wt` from source. This may be due one of the following reasons:

- `ENABLE_POSTGRES` is not checked while configuring `Wt` using `CMake`
- Some [external dependency](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/InstallationUnix.html#requirements), i.e. [`Postgres`](https://www.posgresql.org/), is not met. This should be mentioned in the cmake output. It may be necessary to specify the `Postgres` directory in the `POSTGRES_PREFIX` variable of `CMake`.

Note that `sqlite3` is the only backend which is supported without external dependencies.

Note that the same procedure should be followed for other database too, such as `MySQL` (or `MariaDB`), `Firebird`, ...